# Django: How to access the previous model class instances while creating new instance of the same class?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-views

I have a model in my django app like below:

**models.py**

```
class Profit(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    month = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    total_profit = models.IntegerField()
```

Now, what I want to do is that whenever a new instance/object is created for this class, the user puts the `month` and the `amount` of profit for that month, But I want that it also calculates the total profit the user got up till the current profit, by adding all the profits that was being added in the past.

For example.

if the user is adding the profit for month April, then it add all the values in the `amount` field of previously added objects of (March, February, January and so on..) and put it in the field `total_profit`. So that the user can see how much `total_profit` he got at each new entry.

My views.py where I am printing the list of profits is given below:

**views.py**

```
class ProfitListView(ListView):
    model = Profit
    template_name = 'client_management_system/profit_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'profits'


    # pk=self.kwargs['pk'] is to get the client id/pk from URL
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(Client, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return Profit.objects.filter(client=user)
```

`Client` is the another model in my models.py to which the `Profit` class is connected via ForeignKey

I also don't exactly know how to use window functions inside this view.

Comment: It makes not much sense to store that in the model. You can calculate that when necessary.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please guide that in case I don't save it in model, then where and how to calculate the total_profit? In my views.py I am using Django ListView to print all the months along with their profits, and I also want to print the total_profit in front of every entry.

Comment: @RazaJaved you can use [Window functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) to do this.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thank you. As I am new to Django, and read about using window functions, but not able to understand it completely. Can you please elaborate a bit how can I use them in above mentioned particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments one should generally not store things in the database that can be calculated from other data. Since that leads to duplication and then makes it difficult to update data. Although if your data might not change and this is some financial data one might store it anyway for record keeping purposes.

Firstly `month` as a `CharField` is not a very suitable field of yours for your schema. As firstly they are not easily ordered, secondly it would be better for you to work with a `DateTimeField` instead:

```
class Profit(models.Model):
    month = models.CharField(max_length=100) # Remove this
    made_on = models.DateTimeField() # A `DateTimeField` is better suited
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    total_profit = models.IntegerField()
```

Next since you want to print all the `Profit` instances along with the total amount you should use a [Window function [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) which will be ordered by `made_on` and we will also use a frame *just in case* that the `made_on` is same for two entries:

```py
from django.db.models import F, RowRange, Sum, Window

queryset = Profit.objects.annotate(
    total_amount=Window(
        expression=Sum('amount'),
        order_by=F('made_on').asc(),
        frame=RowRange(end=0)
    )
)

for profit in queryset:
    print(f"Date: {profit.made_on}, Amount: {profit.amount}, Total amount: {profit.total_amount}")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, and it seems like it can solve my problem. I have updated my question a bit, can you please have a look at it.
I have added my views.py file in the question and I am not getting how to include your suggested modifications in my views.