# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) in Django Window function

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want my data to be displayed like this:

```
Date              installment month      amount      total
January 1, 2021   January                30000       30000
February 1, 2021  February               40000       70000 (i.e sum of 30000 and 40000)
March 1, 2021     March                  30000       100000 (i.e sum of 30000, 40000 and 30000)
.
.
and so on..
```

For this purpose I am using aggregate() in my InstallmentListView as given below:

views.py

```
class InstallmentListView(ListView):
    model = Installment
    template_name = 'client_management_system/installment_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'installments'

    # This function is to show the installments of the client, the details of which we are seeing currently, and
    # pk=self.kwargs['pk'] is to get the client id/pk from URL
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(Client, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return Installment.objects.filter(client=user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = get_object_or_404(Client, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        queryset = Installment.objects.annotate(total=Window(expression=Sum('installment_amount'), order_by=F('installment_month').asc(), frame=RowRange(end=0)))
        context['total'] = queryset
        @register.filter
        def get_item(total, key):
            return total.get(key)
        return context`
```

and my template file is given below:

template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "client_management_system/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<body>
  <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"><h5>Installment History</h5></legend>
  <article class="media content-section">
    <div>
      <table id="installmentTable" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th style="width:150px">Date</th>
          <th style="width:250px">Installment Month</th>
          <th style="width:170px">Amount</th>
          <th style="width:100px">Balance</th>
        </tr>
        {% for installment in installments %}
        <fieldset>
          <tr>
            <td>{{ installment.installment_date|date:"F d, Y" }}</td>
            <td>{{ installment.installment_month }}</td>
            <td>{{ installment.installment_amount }}</td>
            <td>{{ total|get_item:'installment_amount__sum' }}</td>
          </tr>
        </fieldset>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>
    </div>
  </article>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

It looks like I am not implementing the Window function correctly. Does anyone has an idea how to resolve this?

Comment: An aggregate would be the total of all the instances... I believe I did show you how to use `Window` functions which will do what you want in this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67098929/django-how-to-access-the-previous-model-class-instances-while-creating-new-inst) of yours? Why are you not using that?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did try that and it is giving me an error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. Can I write my approach in the answer section below?  so that you can have a better idea what I am doing.

Comment: Answers are not meant for asking questions, you should [edit] your question instead to give any clarification.

Comment: I have done it. Maybe now you can get a clear picture. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written:

```
queryset = Installment.objects.annotate(total=Window(expression=Sum('installment_amount'), order_by=F('installment_month').asc(), frame=RowRange(end=0)))
context['total'] = queryset
```

As indicated by the variable name `queryset` is a QuerySet, i.e. a collection of `Installment` instances. Yet later you write `total|get_item:'installment_amount__sum'` which effectively translates to `queryset.get('installment_amount__sum')` which doesn't make sense and obviously gives you an error.

Instead you want to add this window expression to the queryset returned by `get_queryset` instead, also you want to use `order_by` on the **`installment_date`** ordering on a string month doesn't make much sense:

```py
class InstallmentListView(ListView):
    model = Installment
    template_name = 'client_management_system/installment_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'installments'

    # This function is to show the installments of the client, the details of which we are seeing currently, and
    # pk=self.kwargs['pk'] is to get the client id/pk from URL
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(Client, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return Installment.objects.filter(client=user).annotate(
            total=Window(
                expression=Sum('installment_amount'),
                order_by=F('installment_date').asc(),
                frame=RowRange(end=0)
            )
        )
    
    # Remove your `get_context_data`
```

Next in the template you can simply write:

```
{% for installment in installments %}
    <fieldset>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ installment.installment_date|date:"F d, Y" }}</td>
            <td>{{ installment.installment_month }}</td>
            <td>{{ installment.installment_amount }}</td>
            <td>{{ installment.total }}</td>
        </tr>
    </fieldset>
{% endfor %}
```

> **Note**: Why do you even store `installment_month` you can get that from `installment_date`... Plus that custom template tag of yours was
> unnecessary, dictionary lookups can be done in the template as simply
> as `{{ variable.key_name }}`

Comment: Implemented the modifications. it gave the following error:
`django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: This backend does not support window expressions.`

Comment: @RazaJaved what version of Django do you use and which database? If sqlite3 then what version of it (Run `import sqlite3` and `print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)` to check)?

Comment: I am using Django Version 2.1.3, and I am using sqlite3 database and its version is 3.23.1

Comment: @RazaJaved Django supports window expressions in sqlite3 from Django version 3.0 onwards with sqlite3 version being `>=3.25.0` this would work if you could upgrade the versions.